# Extract one element from each row

Tags: r

In R, I have a data frame as follows

```
    J   HE  JUS     HEUS
1   0   0   J-US    0
2   0   0   J-US    0
3   J   0   0       0
4   J   0   0       0
5   0   HE  0       0
6   0   0   0       HE-US
7   0   0   0       0
```

I want to shrink this into 1 column which looks like this

```
1  J-US
2  J-US
3  J
4  J
5  HE
6  HE-US
7  0
```

i.e. check in each row and extract the non-zero element and if there is no non-zero element then use 0.

Comment: What if you have more than element non-zero in one row?

Answer (score 2):

This is another way using `which.max`

```
apply(d, 1, function(x) x[which.max(x != '0')])
#       1       2       3       4       5       6       7 
#  "J-US"  "J-US"     "J"     "J"    "HE" "HE-US"     "0"
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you could do:

```
  df[cbind(1:nrow(df), max.col(df!=0, "first"))]
  #[1] "J-US"  "J-US"  "J"     "J"     "HE"    "HE-US" "0"
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(J = c("0", "0", "J", "J", "0", "0", "0"), HE = c("0", 
"0", "0", "0", "HE", "0", "0"), JUS = c("J-US", "J-US", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0"), HEUS = c("0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "HE-US", 
"0")), .Names = c("J", "HE", "JUS", "HEUS"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ifelse` to check if everything's 0 and extract the value accordingly:

```
data.frame(x=apply(dat, 1, function(x) ifelse(all(x == "0"), "0", head(x[x!="0"], 1))))
#       x
# 1  J-US
# 2  J-US
# 3     J
# 4     J
# 5    HE
# 6 HE-US
# 7     0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Worked perfect!

Answer (score 0):

Another vectorized option using paste :

```
xx <-gsub("0| ","",do.call(paste,dat))
1] "J-US"  "J-US"  "J"     "J"     "HE"    "HE-US" ""
```

Note you get empty character in case you have only zeros in a row. This is more logic than having "0".
In case you want to replace empty character by "0":

```
xx[nzchar(xx)==0] <- "0"
[1] "J-US"  "J-US"  "J"     "J"     "HE"    "HE-US" "0"
```

Note also this answer will work even if you have more than non-zero element in a a row.

Answer (score 0):

One more vectorized solution:

```
w <- which(dne <- df != 0, arr.ind = TRUE)
unname(ifelse(rowSums(dne), df[w[order(rownames(w)),]], 0))
# [1] "J-US"  "J-US"  "J"     "J"     "HE"    "HE-US" "0"
```

Or it's probably easier to do

```
rs <- unname(rowSums(df != 0))
ifelse(rs != 0, t(df)[t(df) != 0], rs[rs == 0])
# [1] "J-US"  "J-US"  "J"     "J"     "HE"    "HE-US" "0"
```